# Problem setting AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandleException in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, prism, clickonce, .net-4.8

In one of my ClickOnce applications I get an `System.MethodAccessException` when I try to subscripe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

My initializations code look like this:

App.xaml:

```
<mylib:MyApplicationBase x:Class="MyApplication.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
    xmlns:mylib="clr-namespace:MyLib;assembly=MyLib"
>
</mydll:MyApplicationBase>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class App : MyApplicationBase
    {
        public App()
        {
            var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            // exception in next line
            domain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
        }

        public void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
}
```

and in another assembly:
MyApplicationBase.cs

```
namespace MyLib
{
    public class MyApplicationBase : System.Windows.Application
    {
        // Some more code but no explicit constructor definitions
    }
}
```

The code run fine on same machine if not installed by ClickOnce

I use a similar approach in other applications without problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the `System.MethodAccessException` instead of the underlying problem. Because the appliaction had Project Properties Security set to:

- Enable ClickOnce security settings: checked
- This is a full trust application: selected

[image]

So the approach I took was:

- uncheck: Enable ClickOnce security settings
- publish (to local folder)
- install and run local to investigate
- fix the now visible underlying error
- check: Enable ClickOnce security settings
- publish
- install and run on target machine